# SQLAlchemy: How do I find second degree relationships in the database?

Tags: python, permissions, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm writing a permission system for my Flask app, and I'm having problems figuring out how to find relationships in the database. [My github repo](https://github.com/raddevon/dcc-admin/tree/permissions), if you want to see everything. The decorator is intended to limit access to decorated views.

```
def user_has(attribute):
    """
    Takes an attribute (a string name of either a role or an ability) and returns the function if the user has that attribute
    """
    def wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            attribute_object = Role.query.filter_by(name=attribute).first() or \
                Ability.query.filter_by(name=attribute).first()

            if attribute_object in current_user.roles or attribute in current_user.roles.abilities.all():
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                # Make this do someting way better.
                return "You do not have access"
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

I'm using SQLAlchemy and storing Users, Roles, and Abilities in the database. Users may have one or more roles. Roles may have one or more abilities. I want to take the string passed to the decorator and check if the user has that role or if one of the user's roles has that ability. The decorator shouldn't care whether it has been called with a role or ability argument.

Apparently, this method (`current_user.roles.abilities.all()`) does not work to get through my relational database as I'm attempting to do here to find `abilities`. I get an error message:

```
AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'abilities'
```

How can I compare the string argument with my current user's abilities which are derived from his/her roles?

For reference, my models:

```
user_role_table = db.Table('user_role',
                           db.Column(
                               'user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.uid')),
                           db.Column(
                           'role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
                           )

role_ability_table = db.Table('role_ability',
                              db.Column(
                                  'role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id')),
                              db.Column(
                              'ability_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ability.id'))
                              )


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    abilities = db.relationship(
        'Ability', secondary=role_ability_table, backref='roles')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name.lower()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role {}>'.format(self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ability(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ability'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name.lower()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Ability {}>'.format(self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    pwdhash = db.Column(db.String(100))
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=user_role_table, backref='users')

    def __init__(self, email, password, roles=None):
        self.email = email.lower()

        # If only a string is passed for roles, convert it to a list containing
        # that string
        if roles and isinstance(roles, basestring):
            roles = [roles]

        # If a sequence is passed for roles (or if roles has been converted to
        # a sequence), fetch the corresponding database objects and make a list
        # of those.
        if roles and is_sequence(roles):
            role_list = []
            for role in roles:
                role_list.appen(Role.query.filter_by(name=role).first())
            self.roles = role_list
        # Otherwise, assign the default 'user' role. Create that role if it
        # doesn't exist.
        else:
            r = Role.query.filter_by(name='user').first()
            if not r:
                r = Role('user')
                db.session.add(r)
                db.session.commit()
            self.roles = [r]

        self.set_password(password)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.pwdhash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.pwdhash, password)

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.uid)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.email)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

and the decorated view:

```
@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@user_has('admin')
def admin():
    users = models.User.query.all()
    forms = {user.uid: RoleForm(uid=user.uid, roles=[role.id for role in user.roles])
             for user in users}

    if request.method == "POST":
        current_form = forms[int(request.form['uid'])]

        if current_form.validate():
            u = models.User.query.get(current_form.uid.data)
            u.roles = [models.Role.query.get(role)
                       for role in current_form.roles.data]
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Roles updated for {}'.format(u))

    return render_template('admin.html', users=users, forms=forms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being dead simple. I feel a bit silly not knowing it from the start.

```
user_abilities = []
for role in current_user.roles:
    user_abilities += [role.ability for ability in role.abilities]
```

I still feel there's probably a better pattern for this, but the solution works without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance this doesn't work because you use `attribute` instead of `attribute_object` in the second clause of your if statement?

Instead of this:

```
 if attribute_object in current_user.roles or attribute in current_user.roles.abilities.all():
```

Try this:

```
 if attribute_object in current_user.roles or attribute_object in current_user.roles.abilities.all():
```

Comment: That's a good catch. I fixed that, but I'm still having the problem I was getting before. `AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'abilities'` It says to me that this is not the way to access the abilities associated with the user's roles, but I don't know the correct way.